# Remove -#### in zipcodes

Tags: python, regex

How do I remove the +4 from zipcodes, in python?

I've got data like

```
85001
52804-3233
Winston-Salem
```

And I want that to become

```
85001
52804
Winston-Salem
```

Comment: What solution have you tried so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could try something like this:

```
for input in inputs:
    if input[:5].isnumeric():
        input = input[:5]
        # Takes the first 5 characters from the string
```

Just take away the first 5 characters of anything that is numbers in the first 5 positions.

Comment: I think you mean `input[0:4]`?

Comment: No, in Python slices, you indicate the first character that you want, followed by the first character you *don't* want. `[0:5]` is the first five elements of a list or string.

Comment: Also, crap!  I realized that the function we wanted is: isdigit() instead of isnumeric().  isnumeric works on unicode rather than strings.  http://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/string_isdigit.htm

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> zip = '52804-3233'
>>> zip[:5]
'52804'
```

...and of course when you parse your lines from the original data you should insert some kind of rule to distinguish between zipcode to fix and other strings, but I don't know how your data looks like, so I can't help much (you could check if they are only digits and the '-' symbol, maybe?).

Answer (score 3):

```
>>> import re
>>> s = "52804-3233"
>>> # regex to remove a dash and 4 digits after the dash after 5 digits:
>>> re.sub('(\d{5})-\d{4}', '\\1', s)
'52804'
```

The `\\1` is a so called back reference and gets replaced by the first group, which would be the 5 digit zipcode in this case.

Answer (score 2):

```
re.sub('-\d{4}$', '', zipcode)
```

Answer (score 1):

This grabs all items of the format `00000-0000` with a space or other word boundary before and after the number and replaces it with the first five digits. The other regex's posted will match some other number formats that you might not want.

```
re.sub('\b(\d{5})-\d{4}\b', '\\1', zipcode)
```

Answer (score 1):

Or without regex:

```
output = [line[:5] if line[:5].isnumeric() and line[6:].isnumeric() else line for line in text if line]
```